# I cannot use camera in genymotion emulator

Tags: android, emulation, genymotion

I am using genymotion emulator http://www.genymotion.com/ but when I opened the camera , I got message "cannot connect to the camera " , what is the problem ?

Comment: Also got the same error on Galaxy Nexus 4.2.2 avd on genymotion. Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

> **UPDATE** Made it a community wiki in case someone else has something to add, I can't keep this updated right now :)

It could just be that you **didn't activate the camera** for the emulator. Opposed to the stock emulators that once you set up the webcam they just work, on genymotion emulators you need to turn the cameras **on**. The process is very simple.

On the emulator window, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> to bring the camera configuration panel that looks like the left, and turn it on like on the right:
[image]

You can select a dummy camera which will show a genymotion logo moving around the screen or use the system camera if it's available and preview it. Note that on the above screenshot I'm using the phone front camera instead of the back camera.

Comment: Got the same problem running MacOSX 10.7 Geny 4.1.1. App with a camera preview doesn't quite work. What's weird is it does sometimes when I switch randomly Dummy to webcam. Suddenly preview works and when switching settings or rebooting app is back to black screen.

Comment: If you keep getting the "Can't connect to the camera"-alert, even though the camera has been set to 'On' in Genymotion, you could try recreating the virtual device. That fixed it for me.

Comment: Even on Windows I cannot see anything on Emulator although I can see my image on preview side. My camera is on, exactly like above part.

Comment: On OSX, I did the following to make it work:
1. Destroy the virtual device
2. From the CLI, adb kill-server
3. Create a new virtual device
4. ionic run android

Answer (score 30):

If all the other solutions do not seem to work you can
 **keep the virtual device working and restart  eclipse, 
 and the adb process** and it should work. It worked for me. My guess is that the connection to adb is already taken by some other camera and that's blocking your current camera from connecting to the IDE development with the virtual device.

Comment: Thx man! You save my time from trying ANOTHER "best" emulator... When I got this problem, turn off Eclipse > restart Genymotion > On camera widget > start Eclipse.

Comment: actually shutting adb (it automatically restarts) is enough you don't have to restart eclipse.

Comment: Oh man , i can't believe how you got this idea ;) it works for me

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Intellij Idea no need to restart Genymotion or IDE.

1. Genymotion: Switch off camera
2. Intellij IDEA: From menu select Tools/Android/"Enable ADB Integration"
3. Genymotion: Switch on camera

It should works for you as well.

Comment: I allready had it selected, although I just un selected then re selected and it worked! Using Android studio 1.0.2. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

**Just expanding the @sivi's answer:**

In my case, i just re-established the connection to emulator using these :

```
adb kill-server ---> adb start-server
```

and it started working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using eclipse, I found out going to DDMS and then Devices you can reset the adb. You can find the option by clicking on the drop down arrow that says "View Menu".

[Example to find Rest adb.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU5oR.png)

Answer (score 1):

just end your ADB.exe process or similar in MacOS kill adb and it will automatically re start hence genymotion needs it and you will be able to use your camera, ADB is probably keeping the cam busy.

Answer (score 1):

I tryied all the suggestions above including restart adb but None worked
Then I see a suggestion on an English-language website
My English is not good so I can not totally understand it and I forget the URL of the page..

However the final suggestion is delete your virtual device in genymotion and just re-create a same one, maybe you will work.

I followed that advice and I succeeded.
So I come here to share.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution.
I've tried all of the above and frustruately none of them worked.
Eventually I found out that if I **rotate the device to landscape** the camera is working. otherwise I get the green screen.
Hope that helps someone..