# Cannot access genymotion camera?

Tags: android, camera, genymotion

I switched on the camera in settings and can see stuff on the preview [image]

but the camera doesn't work, I thought it was my program that called the camera wrongly but the default camera app also doesn't work[image]

I really don't want to go back to using eclipse's AVD!. TIA

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24078028/513413

Answer (score 7):

I just encountered this problem and the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889777/i-cannot-use-camera-in-genymotion-emulator/22592413#22592413) worked like a charm.

Comment: If you're going to link to a answer please add a quick description of what the solution was. Thanks!

Comment: If you hover over the 'here', you see a small description. But I will keep that in mind for the future, thank you. Anyway, I ran the Genymotion emulator outside of the IDE and the camera seems to work. This means that the problem is with the IDE plugin. One way around this is to start the emulator from outside the IDE (before opening the IDE) and leave it running. Another solution is the one described in that other post.

Comment: Disable the camera in Genymotion, then in Android Studio, select Tools/Android/"Enable ADB Integration", then turn on the camera in Genymotion, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I use genymotion as well, its great:D make sure no other apps are trying to access your camera. Also if you have a firewall make sure its not blocking access to the camera. If you have a camera on your computer you could try to switch the front or back camera option in genymotion to your computers camera instead of dummy camera. As a last result try to Create another emulator.