# How to run mobile vision apps based on google api 2017 on genymotion?

Tags: android, google-play-services, genymotion, android-vision

How can i run [mobile vision api](https://developers.google.com/vision/introduction) projects on genymotion,
my projects work correctly on my tablet and mobile phone but not working on genymotion although i have installed [google play service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43179659/4376397).

Answer (score 0):

1. Check out [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21364340/3289257) to connect your laptop's webcam or your
   external webcam to genymotion.
2. Double check your Google Play Store
   installation or install an avd with built in play store.
3. Then try and run the mobile vision project.

PS :- I haven't run it like that, but I will definitely update the answer soon after trying it.

Good Luck !

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the problem was with my google account and i solved by creating another google account.

Comment: Glad to see your problem was fixed. Although I'm curious to know what exactly was the issue with your google account..